# Identificar cidades ou demais assuntos

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Boa tarde, amigos.
Eu estou criando um site para uma empresa e estou com uma pequena dúvida.
alguém pode me dizer como faço para que o site "auto complete" as cidades do usuário?
EX: no  de estado eu seleciono que moro em São Paulo, e automaticamente o  de cidades, Me mostra só as cidades de são Paulo.
Se não fui claro o suficiente, me perdoem.

Comment: Veja esse link: http://www.daviferreira.com/posts/populando-selects-de-cidades-e-estados-com-ajax-php-e-jquery Nele tem o que você procura :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um arquivo que faça apenas um `return` em um array gigante com todos os nomes ou consultar diretamente uma API

1. [Json de Cidade](https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978) para utilizar com o arquivo
2. [API com siglas da cidade](http://educacao.dadosabertosbr.com/api/docs/%2Fapi%2Fcidades%2F%7Bestado%7D)

Para popular o outro `select` faça uma request com o valor do primeiro input e preencha o segundo com os valores retornados.